# how to optimize the C code, when m is too big, it can't operation

Tags: c

I want to get the minimum through the code below, now it can run, but when m is a big number, the code can't run, how to operate the code to make it better.

gx1,gx2,gx3 and gx4 are functions that compute the minimum value

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define n 3
#define m 8
int gx1(int x1);
int gx2(int x1,int x2);
int gx3(int x1,int x2,int x3);
int gx4(int x1,int x2,int x3,int x4);

int main()
{
    int min;
    FILE *fp=fopen("result4.txt","w");
    if(!fp)
    {
        printf("Error to open the file!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    for(int x1=1;x1<m;x1++)
    {
        for(int x2=1;x2<m;x2++)
        {
            for(int x3=1;x3<m;x3++)
            {
                for(int x4=1;x4<m;x4++)
                {
                    min=gx4(x1,x2,x3,x4);
                    fprintf(fp,"g(%d,%d,%d,%d)=%d\t",x1,x2,x3,x4,min);
                }
                fprintf(fp,"\n");
            }
            fprintf(fp,"\n");
        }
        fprintf(fp,"\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
int gx1(int x1)
{
    int min,temp,i;
    if(x1==0 || x1==1)  
    min = x1;   
    else
    {
       min=(gx1(0)+1)%n;
       for (i=1;i<=x1-1;i++)
       {
           temp=(gx1(i)+1)%n;
           if (temp<min)
           min=temp;
        }      
    }
    return min;
}
int gx2(int x1,int x2)
{
    int min,temp,i;
    if(x1==0)
    min=gx1(x2);

    else if(x2==0)
    min=gx1(x1);

    else if(x1==1&&x2==1)
    min=2;
    else
    {

        for(i=1,min=(gx2(0,x2)+1)%n;i<=x1-1;i++)
        {
            temp=(gx2(i,x2)+1)%n;
            if(temp<min)
            min=temp;
        }
        for(i=0;i<=x2-1;i++)
        {
            temp=(gx2(x1,i)+1)%n;
            if(temp<min)
            min=temp;
        }
    }
    return min; 
}

int gx3(int x1,int x2,int x3)
{
    int min,temp,i;

    if(x1==0)
    min=gx2(x2,x3);

    else if(x2==0)
        min=gx2(x1,x3);

    else if(x3==0)
        min=gx2(x1,x2);

    else
    {
        for(i=1,min=(gx2(x2,x3)+1)%n;i<=x1-1;i++)
        {
            temp=(gx3(i,x2,x3)+1)%n;
            if(temp<min)
            min=temp;
        }
        for(i=0;i<=x2-1;i++)
        {
            temp=(gx3(x1,i,x3)+1)%n;
            if(temp<min)
            min=temp;
        }
        for(i=0;i<=x3-1;i++)
        {
            temp=(gx3(x1,x2,i)+1)%n;
            if(temp<min)
            min=temp;
        }
    }
    return min; 
}
int gx4(int x1,int x2,int x3,int x4)
{
    int min,temp,i;

    if(x1==0)
    min=gx3(x2,x3,x4);

    else if(x2==0)
    min=gx3(x1,x3,x4);

    else if(x3==0)
    min=gx3(x1,x2,x4);

    else if(x4==0)
    min=gx3(x1,x2,x3);

    else
    {
        for(i=1,min=(gx3(x2,x3,x4)+1)%n;i<=x1-1;i++)
        {
            temp=(gx4(i,x2,x3,x4)+1)%n;
            if(temp<min)
            min=temp;
        }
        for(i=0;i<=x2-1;i++)
        {
            temp=(gx4(x1,i,x3,x4)+1)%n;
            if(temp<min)
            min=temp;
        }
        for(i=0;i<=x3-1;i++)
        {
            temp=(gx4(x1,x2,i,x4)+1)%n;
            if(temp<min)
            min=temp;
        }
        for(i=0;i<=x4-1;i++)
        {
            temp=(gx4(x1,x2,x3,i)+1)%n;
            if(temp<min)
            min=temp;
        }

    }
    return min; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it can't"?

Comment: @immibis  "it can't"  I mean "the code cann't run"

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't run"?

Comment: I guess.. the purpose of this code is to find the four smallest values?

Comment: @M.M yeah, the purpose of this code is to find the four smallest values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce some of the computations by keeping running minimum values in each of the loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define m 8

int main()
{
   int min;
   int min1;
   int min2;
   int min3;
   int min4;

   FILE* fp = stdout;
   for(int x1=1;x1<m;x1++)
   {
      min1 = x1;
      for(int x2=1;x2<m;x2++)
      {
         min2 = min1;
         if ( min2 > x2 )
            min2 = x2;

         for(int x3=1;x3<m;x3++)
         {
            min3 = min2;
            if ( min3 > x3 )
               min3 = x3;

            for(int x4=1;x4<m;x4++)
            {
               min4 = min3;
               if (min4 > x4 )
                  min4 = x4;

               min=min4;
               fprintf(fp, "g(%d,%d,%d,%d)=%d\n",x1,x2,x3,x4,min);
            }
            fprintf(fp,"\n");
         }
         fprintf(fp,"\n");
      }
      fprintf(fp,"\n");
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

However, you have a O(N^4) computational complexity with `m`. If you keep increasing the value of `m`, the time taken to go through the loops increases rather rapidly.